# iOS: Location Manager get updated headings for several table cells, who is the delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I've never used CLLocations so far. What I want is to save a position by clicking on a button into core data. This works. I just start the location update when the button gets clicked, save the position to the database in the delegate method didUpdateLocation and then stop updating again.

What I want now is to show the heading to this position. Since there can be several positions (several table cells) I want to show the heading to each of these positions in the table view cells. Now my problem is that the table view controller contains the LocationManager and is the delegate for it. For the headings the table view cells should be the delegate, but can this work? Or where should I implement the didUpdateHeading delegate method?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the view controller as the delegate. When you get the location/heading update, update your data model used as the table's data source. Then reload the table view rows so the cells can show their updated info based on the updated data model.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a singleton class to handle the location manager changes and store the current location and heading. After that you'll be able to add KVO to this singleton or to send a notification when the location changes. You will also save a lot of battery.

Comment: How does this save battery?

Comment: I understood that can be more than one CLLocationManager handling the changes and it seems that just object would be enough to handle the location and heading changes. This way it also would be easier to handle location manager stopUpdatingLocation call.